# How to validate a file starts with certain perfix format?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of files with names like this.

`["TYBN-220422-257172171.txt",  "TYBN-120522-257172174.txt", "TYBN-320422-657172171.txt", "TYBN-220622-237172174.txt", "TYBN-FRTRE-FFF.txt",....]`

I want to get only the files which has format like this `TYBN-220422-257172171.txt`

`valid = "TYBN-{}-{}".format(numericvalue, numericvalue)` I want this type of files only in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex explanation:

- **^** start of the string
- **$** end of the string
- **\d** matches all numbers. Equivalent to [0-9]
- **+** one or many of the expressions

```py
import re

files = ["TYBN-220422-257172171.txt", "TYBN-120522-257172174.txt"]

pattern = re.compile("^TYBN-\d+-\d+\.txt$")

for f in files:
    if pattern.match(f):
        print(f + " matched naming convention.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer .One more request If I want to add one more condition while matching . here `-220422-257172171` the length should be 6 and 9 respectively. how can I do this here ?

Comment: `re.compile("^TYBN-\d{6}-\d{9}\.txt$")` ? i think it will work.

Comment: @D_P that would work, as I said in my answer, you don't need the starting `^` as `re.match` always anchors matches to the start of the string anyway. So just `TYBN-\d{6}-\d{9}\.txt$`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably most easily done using a regex to match the desired format i.e.

```regex
TYBN-\d+-\d+\.txt$
```

which looks for a name starting with the characters `TYBN-` followed by one or more digits (`\d+`), a `-`, some more digits and then finishing with `.txt`.

Note that when using [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.match) (as in the code below), matches are automatically anchored to the start of the string and thus a leading `^` (start-of-string anchor) is not required on the regex.

In python:

```py
import re
filelist = ["TYBN-220422-257172171.txt",
            "TYBN-120522-257172174.txt",
            "TYBN-320422-657172171.txt",
            "TYBN-220622-237172174.txt",
            "TYBN-FRTRE-FFF.txt"
           ]
regex = re.compile(r'TYBN-\d+-\d+\.txt$')
valid = [file for file in filelist if regex.match(file)]
```

Output:

```
[
 'TYBN-220422-257172171.txt',
 'TYBN-120522-257172174.txt',
 'TYBN-320422-657172171.txt',
 'TYBN-220622-237172174.txt'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```py
lst = ["TYBN-220422-257172171.txt",  "TYBN-120522-257172174.txt", "TYBN-320422-657172171.txt", "TYBN-220622-237172174.txt", "TYBN-FRTRE-FFF.txt"]

valid_format = ['TYBN',True,True] # here true for digits
valid = []

for a in lst:
    l = a.replace('.txt','').split('-')
    if l[0] == valid_format[0]:
        if [i.isdigit() for i in l[1:]] == valid_format[1:]:
                valid.append(a)

print(valid)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
['TYBN-220422-257172171.txt',
 'TYBN-120522-257172174.txt',
 'TYBN-320422-657172171.txt',
 'TYBN-220622-237172174.txt']
```

Comment: The *re* module was invented to obviate the need for this kind of code